# Using profiling tools with rebar

Tags: erlang, profiling, rebar, rebar3

I'm using rebar3 to build my application. I need to track down some performance problems and want to use fprof but it doesnt seem to be included in the release made by rebar.

How can I get fprof (or eprof) included in the rebar release?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the application **tools** to the relx section to your project's rebar.config:

```
{relx, [{release, {<release name>, "0.0.1"},
         [<app>,tools]},

        {dev_mode, true},
        {include_erts, false},

        {extended_start_script, true}]}.
```

tools is the application containing **fprof** module.

For using the fprof module, [this](http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2009-January/041380.html) is a good entry-level explanation from the erlang mailing list. [Here](http://erlang.org/documentation/doc-5.5.5/lib/tools-2.5.5/doc/html/index.html) are other profiling tools applicable to erlang.